# problems with boldsymbol and cmbright

Tags: bold, boldmath, boldsymbol

Καλημέρα!

If I use the package `cmbright` the command `\boldsymbol{}` does not work for math symbols (e.g. <, +, 45), but only for letters.

1. What is the problem?
2. I don't remember the purpose that I used `cmbright`. What is it doing and what are the problems of not having it?

[image]

The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\textlatin{some text} κείμενο}

$\boldsymbol{4+y\alpha<89x}$

$4<89x$

\end{document}
```

Ευχαριστώ εκ των προτέρων!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cmbright` apparently does not have bold variant of all the symbols.  You could use `\pmb` [1] instead, but then you'd also get poor man's bold for glyph which have a bold variant.  The easiest solution is to use the `bm` package.  This will use bold glyphs where available and poor man's bold otherwise.  It's important that you load the `bm` package *after* loading your math font.

[1] *poor man's bold:* printing a letter multiple times with slight offset to get a fake bold effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{bm} % load after fonts

\begin{document}

\textbf{\textlatin{some text} κείμενο}

$\bm{4+y\alpha<89x}$

$4<89x$

\end{document}
```

I made a high-resolution screenshot.  It should be easy to spot the poor man's bold.

[image]

Comment: 1) If I use the package bm, the command `\boldsymbol{}` works again!!! Should I use the `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol{}` or are the same?

2) Is any reason to keep the cmbright package?

Comment: @ΚώσταςΚούδας The `bm` package redefines `\boldsymbol` to do the same as `\bm`.  I prefer `\bm` because it's only three keystrokes.

Comment: @ΚώσταςΚούδας Regarding the `cmbirght` package, I kept it because it was part of your example.  It provides the Computer Modern Bright font, a sans-serif font for text and math.